# I need help using VBA in excel for a Call Detail Report

Tags: vba, excel, csv

I dumped some CDR files from our phone system and I need to sort out the data in the CVS file to make an easy read report. Doing it manually takes almost all day long to do it as we get countless calls. I found this code one here which works great to delete all the columns I don't need. However, it's only doing part of what I need to do.

Other things I would like to do to the file are:

- Change time from epoch "xxxxxxxxxx" to time "dd/mm/yy hh:mm:ss"
- Autofit Column Width
- Change the column names from "dateTimeOrigination" to "Date Time" etc.
- Apply this automatically to any CDR.cvs dump file I open.

I am using Excel 2016.

```
Sub deleteIrrelevantColumns()
Dim keepColumn As Boolean
Dim currentColumn As Integer
Dim columnHeading As String


currentColumn = 1
While currentColumn <= ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Columns.Count
columnHeading = ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Cells(1, currentColumn).Value


'CHECK WHETHER TO KEEP THE COLUMN
keepColumn = False
If columnHeading = "dateTimeOrigination" Then keepColumn = True
If columnHeading = "callingPartyNumber" Then keepColumn = True
If columnHeading = "originalCalledPartyNumber" Then keepColumn = True
If columnHeading = "finalCalledPartyNumber" Then keepColumn = True
If columnHeading = "dateTimeConnect" Then keepColumn = True
If columnHeading = "dateTimeDisconnect" Then keepColumn = True
If columnHeading = "lastRedirectDn" Then keepColumn = True
If columnHeading = "duration" Then keepColumn = True




If keepColumn Then
'IF YES THEN SKIP TO THE NEXT COLUMN,
currentColumn = currentColumn + 1
Else
'IF NO DELETE THE COLUMN
ActiveSheet.Columns(currentColumn).Delete
End If


'LASTLY AN ESCAPE IN CASE THE SHEET HAS NO COLUMNS LEFT
If (ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Address = "$A$1") And 
(ActiveSheet.Range("$A$1").Text = "") Then Exit Sub
Wend


End Sub
```

Comment: With a little bit of research I found this formula that might help you convert epoch time to a readable date `=TEXT(DATE(1970,1,1)+A1/86400,"dd/mm/yy hh:mm:ss")` I did read somewhere that timezone does affect this, however don't quote me on that

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at the refactored code below and stick that in the `ThisWokbook` module of your VBA project, this sub is triggered by the `workbook_open` event and should fire every time this particular document is opened.

If you want to automatically have this apply to new files, you would have to create VBA project in a file, which opens new files, processes them and saves them. It may be a little more complicated but if you do some research on it you should be able to do it.

```
Private Sub Workbook_Open()
    Dim blnColDeleted As Boolean, blnEpoch As Boolean
    Dim columnHeading As String, strFormat As String
    Dim i As Long, j As Long
    Dim arrTMP As Variant
    Dim lngTMP As Long

    With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1")                                                      'Change Sheet1 to your actual sheetname
        For i = .UsedRange.Columns.Count To 1 Step -1                                           'Create a for loop which steps backwards to compensate for deleted columns
            blnColDeleted = False                                                               'Reset some variables for the next column
            blnEpoch = False
            columnHeading = emptyy
            strFormat = Empty
            Select Case .Cells(1, i)
                Case "dateTimeOrigination", "Date Time"
                    columnHeading = "Date Time"                                                 'Change to what you actually want the columnheading to be, goes for all cases
                    strFormat = "dd/mm/yy hh:mm:ss;@"                                             'Change the string to change the format to suit your needs
                    blnEpoch = True                                                             'If this column contains epoch timestamps, set to true to convert them
                Case "callingPartyNumber", "Calling Number"
                    columnHeading = "Calling Number"
                    strFormat = Empty                                                           'Change to desired formatting, leave empty if no formatting required"
                    blnEpoch = False
                Case "originalCalledPartyNumber", "Original Calld Party Number"
                    columnHeading = "Original Calld Party Number"
                    strFormat = Empty
                    blnEpoch = False
                Case "finalCalledPartyNumber", "Final Called Party Number"
                    columnHeading = "Final Called Party Number"
                    strFormat = Empty
                    blnEpoch = False
                Case "dateTimeConnect", "Date Time Connect"
                    columnHeading = "Date Time Connect"
                    strFormat = "dd/mm/yy hh:mm:ss;@"
                    blnEpoch = True
                Case "dateTimeDisconnect", "Date Time Disconnect"
                    columnHeading = "Date Time Disconnect"
                    strFormat = "dd/mm/yy hh:mm:ss;@"
                    blnEpoch = True
                Case "lastRedirectDn", "Last Redirect Dn"
                    columnHeading = "Last Redirect Dn"
                    strFormat = Empty
                    blnEpoch = False
                Case "duration", "Duration"
                    columnHeading = "Duration"
                    strFormat = "[m]:ss;@"                                                       'The square brackets around "mm" show elapsed minutes
                    blnEpoch = False
                Case Else
                    blnColDeleted = True
                    .Columns(i).Delete                                                          'If the column header does not match any of the cases, then it is deleted
            End Select
            If Not blnColDeleted Then
                .Cells(1, i) = columnHeading
                If blnEpoch And Not .Cells(2, i) < Now() Then
                    arrTMP = .Range(.Cells(2, i), .Cells(2, i).End(xlDown))                     'Introduced arrays to quickly convert large batches instead of cell by cell. Continous read write operations directly interacting with the sheet will be very resource heavy
                    For j = LBound(arrTMP, 1) To UBound(arrTMP, 1)
                        lngTMP = arrTMP(j, 1)
                        arrTMP(j, 1) = timeCorrected(lngTMP)
                    Next j
                    With .Range(.Cells(1, i).Offset(1, 0), .Cells(1, i).Offset(UBound(arrTMP, 1), 0))
                        .Value = arrTMP
                        .NumberFormat = strFormat
                    End With
                ElseIf Not strFormat = Empty Then
                    .Range(.Cells(2, i), .Cells(2, i).End(xlDown)).NumberFormat = strFormat
                End If
                .Columns(i).AutoFit
            End If
        Next i
    End With
End Sub
```

Add the function below to a module so it can be referenced by any procedure. This function returns the epoch time in UTC-6 (CST) and UTC-5 (CST with DST) between 2nd Sunday of March of that year and the 1st Sunday of November of that year in an Excel Date time format (days counted since 0/1/1900, and the time behind the decimal symbol, for example 24/05/2017 12:00:00 = 42879.5). I've edited the code above to incorporate this function. I hope this helps and you can take it from here.

```
Function timeCorrected(myEpoch As Long) As Double
    Dim lngYear As Long, lngMonth As Long, lngDay As Long
    Dim dblTime As Double, dblStartDST As Double, dblEndDST As Double
    Dim i As Long

    dblTime = DateAdd("s", myEpoch - 21600, "01/01/1970") 'Time is converted to CST without DST correction (UTC - 6)

    lngYear = Year(dblTime)
    lngMonth = Month(dlbtime)
    lngDay = Day(dblTime)

    'DST starts second Sunday in March
    For i = DateSerial(lngYear, 3, 8) To DateSerial(lngYear, 3, 14)
        If Application.WorksheetFunction.Weekday(i, 2) = 7 Then
            dblStartDST = i + TimeSerial(2, 0, 0)
            Exit For
        End If
    Next

    'DST ends first sunday in november
    For i = DateSerial(lngYear, 11, 1) To DateSerial(lngYear, 11, 7)
        If Application.WorksheetFunction.Weekday(i, 2) = 7 Then
            dblEndDST = i + TimeSerial(2, 0, 0)
            Exit For
        End If
    Next

    If dblTime >= dblStartDST And dblTime < dblEndDST Then
        timeCorrected = dblTime + TimeSerial(1, 0, 0)
    Else
        timeCorrected = dblTime
    End If

End Function
```

---

As for the deletion of all columns encountered, I've discovered 1 typo in the `lastRedirectDN`which caused the wrongful deletion of that column.

But more likely what happened is that you've run this macro twice. After the first time running this macro, all column headings will be different which will result in all columns being deleted because all columns will fail the check whether they are to be kept or not.

This can be fixed by adding the new column heading to the case like below but make sure that whatever you set your column heading to, it is identical to what is in the `Case`

```
Case "dateTimeOrigination", "Date Time"
    columnHeading = "Date Time"
    strFormat = "dd/mm/yy hh:mm:ss"
Case "callingPartyNumber", "Calling Number"
    columnHeading = "Calling Number"
    strformat = Empty
```

As for the epoch conversion, I completely missed that, I've edited the original code above to allow epoch conversion.

Comment: I tried using your code but it deleted everything on my sheet. I did change the name of the sheet to the name of my project. I tried the code by itself and also before and after the one, I used to delete the columns with the same result. Also, the time on the sheet is on epoch time example 1507525449 and would have to be converted to dd/mm/yy hh:mm:ss . Thank you for your help it is greatly appreciated.

Comment: @user2604232, I've edited the code in my post and elaborated on it, I hope this helps.

Comment: Thank you for your time and patience. I tried this again and I got a "Compile error: Next without For." As for the time conversion will it be converted to my time zone? -6 central time? Thanks!

Comment: @user2604232 you must have omitted an End IF, double check your code, I'm pretty sure if you add an End If before Wend, then it should work...

Comment: No problem at all @user2604232. I missed an `End if` to close out the `If blnEpoch Then` which caused that error, which has been fixed in the code above. As far as the epoch conversion, I'm not sure, assuming the epoch time is counted from from 1-1-1970 00:00:00 UTC, then no. If you want to convert that, you'd have to subtract `6 × 3,600` from the epoch time and hen convert it (I think), but if your country/state observes daylight savings, which UTC/GMT does not, you'd also have to compensate for that.

Comment: Thank you for all your help and explanations which make me understand and learn a bit of how this works. I ran the code and got a Run-time Error '6': Overflow in line.Cells(j, i) = DateAdd("s", .Cells(j, i), "01/01/1970 00:00:00"). We do observe daylight savings here and where would I subtract the 6 x 3,600 ?

Comment: The overflow error is caused by the epoch time, being converted twice and reformatted and ended up being something that it couldn't handle. I've written an update for that. As for the time conversion to a local time which observes is actually quite difficult. [This video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-5wpm-gesOY) explains it quite well.

Comment: That being said, and assuming you're only in one zone, and don't ever ask me to incorporate more zones, what state/city are you in?

Comment: Wow I need to learn all this stuff what would be a good course or tutorial to start with. It's really caught my attention. The state would be Texas and the city Eagle Pass. Thanks!

Comment: To be honest, I'm self taught, learned by StackOverflow, Google, and just trying. I'm short on time at the moment so bear with me.

Comment: @user2604232, I've updated the code and added a function to do a conversion to your local time. As you may be able to see from this, if you incorporate more zones, you will get exponentially more logic rules and exceptions to those rules as there is no uniformity to timezones. And as an added bonus, Calls that happen around the moment DST starts or ends, may end up as ending before they were answered due to the none linear nature of human readable times and timezones.